# WiFi only works AFTER suspend on Antergos

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, intel, antergos

I recently swapped the SSD from my old Thinkpad W520 that stopped working into my new Thinkpad T540p. I was just curious what would happen so I let it boot up and it works almost perfectly. However, the wireless only works **after** I resume from suspend. This is quite opposite everything else I've seen about this issue and I haven't been able to find anything online about it, the closest being an [issue about Bluetooth](https://forum.antergos.com/topic/11424/bluetooth-only-works-after-suspend-and-wake-up-gnome-thinkpad-e585/4).

This started happening after I ran a fairly large set of updates, but I'm not sure what exactly caused it. I would suspect there is a driver/config issue at play, but both cards are Intel chips so I don't think it's an issue of Broadcom/Intel.

Related output of `lspci -v`:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at f2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Output of `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 61440  0
hid                   139264  2 usbhid,hid_generic
ccm                    20480  6
isofs                  49152  0
rfcomm                 86016  16
fuse                  131072  7
cmac                   16384  1
bnep                   28672  2
8021q                  40960  0
garp                   16384  1 8021q
mrp                    20480  1 8021q
stp                    16384  1 garp
llc                    16384  2 stp,garp
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
arc4                   16384  2
joydev                 28672  0
mousedev               24576  0
intel_rapl             28672  0
rmi_smbus              16384  0
iwlmvm                446464  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
rmi_core               90112  1 rmi_smbus
btusb                  57344  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
uvcvideo              114688  0
btrtl                  20480  1 btusb
coretemp               20480  0
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                28672  1 btusb
kvm_intel             311296  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  2 rmi_core,uvcvideo
mac80211              942080  1 iwlmvm
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  2 rmi_core,uvcvideo
bluetooth             647168  41 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
videobuf2_common       57344  3 rmi_core,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
iwlwifi               348160  1 iwlmvm
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
videodev              225280  4 rmi_core,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
i915                 2162688  6
ecdh_generic           24576  2 bluetooth
kvmgt                  32768  0
vfio_mdev              16384  0
mdev                   24576  2 kvmgt,vfio_mdev
vfio_iommu_type1       32768  0
vfio                   36864  3 kvmgt,vfio_mdev,vfio_iommu_type1
ofpart                 20480  0
cmdlinepart            16384  0
kvm                   741376  2 kvmgt,kvm_intel
intel_spi_platform     16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
intel_spi              24576  1 intel_spi_platform
uas                    28672  0
media                  57344  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
aesni_intel           372736  6
mei_wdt                16384  0
spi_nor                49152  1 intel_spi
snd_hda_codec_generic    90112  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
cfg80211              798720  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
snd_hda_intel          45056  4
mtd                    73728  5 cmdlinepart,intel_spi,ofpart
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
wmi_bmof               16384  0
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 28672  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
drm_kms_helper        208896  1 i915
intel_cstate           16384  0
snd_hda_codec         155648  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
intel_uncore          135168  0
drm                   499712  5 drm_kms_helper,i915
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_hda_core           98304  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
input_leds             16384  0
psmouse               172032  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               135168  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
intel_gtt              24576  1 i915
agpgart                53248  2 intel_gtt,drm
tpm_tis                16384  0
thinkpad_acpi         110592  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
pcspkr                 16384  0
tpm_tis_core           24576  1 tpm_tis
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_timer              40960  1 snd_pcm
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,thinkpad_acpi
i2c_i801               36864  0
rtsx_pci_ms            24576  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
tpm                    69632  2 tpm_tis,tpm_tis_core
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
e1000e                282624  0
rfkill                 28672  9 bluetooth,thinkpad_acpi,cfg80211
snd                   102400  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_pcm
mei_me                 45056  1
ac                     16384  0
battery                24576  1 thinkpad_acpi
rng_core               16384  1 tpm
evdev                  20480  22
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                   118784  3 mei_wdt,mei_me
ie31200_edac           16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
lpc_ich                28672  0
wmi                    32768  1 wmi_bmof
pcc_cpufreq            20480  0
vboxnetflt             32768  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxpci                28672  0
vboxdrv               491520  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
sg                     40960  0
crypto_user            16384  0
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               49152  1 ip_tables
ext4                  749568  3
crc32c_generic         16384  0
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  131072  1 ext4
fscrypto               32768  1 ext4
dm_mod                151552  9
usb_storage            73728  1 uas
sr_mod                 28672  0
cdrom                  69632  1 sr_mod
sd_mod                 57344  3
serio_raw              20480  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         32768  0
ahci                   40960  2
atkbd                  36864  0
mmc_core              176128  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
libahci                40960  1 ahci
libps2                 20480  2 atkbd,psmouse
libata                274432  2 libahci,ahci
crc32c_intel           24576  6
scsi_mod              249856  6 sd_mod,usb_storage,uas,libata,sg,sr_mod
xhci_pci               20480  0
rtsx_pci               73728  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
ehci_pci               20480  0
xhci_hcd              258048  1 xhci_pci
ehci_hcd               98304  1 ehci_pci
i8042                  32768  0
serio                  28672  8 rmi_core,serio_raw,atkbd,psmouse,i8042
```

Clearly, it's not best practice to swap in a drive and go with it, but everything else seems to be working and if I can avoid reinstalling I'd like that. What can I do about making sure my WiFi works as soon as I log in, instead of having to suspend and then go?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this. Turns out I had enabled multiple network services (`netctl`, `NetworkManager`, and `wpa_supplicant`) and they were conflicting.

Disabling `netctl` and `wpa_supplicant` via `sudo systemctl disable netctl`, `sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant` and then rebooting resolved the issue.